# Get certain value from returned multi-type array

Tags: typescript

I have a function/hook which returns an array with types `boolean` and `MyErrorType`

```
export declare const getErrorData: () => readonly [ boolean, MyErrorType ];
```

In some scenarios I am only interested in the 2nd value of the array of type `MyErrorType` and I was wondering if there is a clean way to get this? Currently only solution I could get to work is just fetching the 2nd element in the array i.e.

```
const error = getErrorData()[1];
```

Is there any way to fetch the element of the array based on the type of the variable? something like

```
const error: MyErrorType = getErrorData();
```

Comment: If you don't feel clean about using 2nd value from array, why would you return array in the first place instead of object like `{ flag: boolean; type: MyErrorType }`?

Comment: It is used elsewhere. In this scenario I only need the 2nd value. I could initialize it with both variables but linting complains when there are unused variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of a program based on types, because the idea of Typescript is that types will be erased and only the resulting Javascript will be run.

You could return an object instead of an array as @tymzap suggests, another solution is to use destructuring:

```
const [, error] = getErrorData();
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of destructing and omitting the first variable over just referencing the index? i.e. `getErrorData()[1]`

Comment: No, they're basically equivalent. It's maybe just more readable depending on your esthetic preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely does not answer your question, but seemed like a good challenge to create a type that iterates over an array and returns the index of an expected type.
Its pure type definition, here you go:

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBRATsg9sgKvADgU2jwA8AXPAOwBMYV1loBvAXwFgAod4nDE6SvUGGQFgachF4BzPCVoYAImBJgAXNAAUASmgBeAHzRhYSmJDxoAbWgAjNGhB4w5ADRwkqDNnzQAugG52dhJcAgBxZDBrAEkqYgB5ADMvPAAedmhoTGd06ABBQlIKamgneAsfaAAfQ0cTcjMS8jKfbLYMgGEAV1QCsioYck6AW2s8eh08iwAiB3JJEgALKZacqMoiXqKB4dHx6AAGVoMJrp7iPuKARhyAfkn9ivOtzOgcjLu1ojfoNXI8ADcxjk1Pknv1LKVXAA6GHQACW5ASY2gACU8BIKtUjHUGhZIdAYVD4YjkWiMd87uFIjF%20EREskUllLITUeiSC1oABlTrWOJ-FKnZB6Vy5SiUPmpT56PTfX4AoFsAIcNjBbyYTo4BwpABym3BgxGY1cmD1xVK5V0lh8x0y01m8yWj0K4O1t0ywMyGq12tcFhZTNK1qVQRCeTFEpSoOdxQNuxt6s1qVyBjBxT9sIRSPoAFUKnc8U1obDc3aKA7lj9oH9AchgyrQ9zefyoxdtoahZaE1rk6aYBYcoTM8js60MqV2D43dnS3NFssPdWxnWuDxoKqwjI5MhFMo0SRuuRLXuDwz12gEtBpLIPNulGA9HX1zZLVTorE6UkQikEFvkq5QpuN47mAx7IOQD7sAA9JB0DXMqT6UC%20gF0MBoHkBY1j%20FBME-jeyRAA)

Short edition:

```
type GrabIndexOfType<
  T,
  A extends any[] | readonly any[],
  Curr extends number = A["length"],
  Idx extends number = 0,
> = Curr extends 1
  ? A[0] extends T 
    ? Idx
    : never
  : A extends [any, ... infer Rest] | readonly [any, ... infer Rest]
    ? GrabIndexOfType<T, [... Rest], SubOne<Curr>, AddOne<Idx>>
    : never
;

type Tuple<N extends number, T extends any[] = []> = T["length"] extends N
  ? T
  : Tuple<N, [... T, any]>;

type AddOne<A extends number> = Tuple<A> extends [... infer U] ? [any, ... U]["length"] : never;

type SubOne<A extends number> = Tuple<A> extends [
  ...infer U,
  any
]
  ? U["length"]
  : never;

type b = GrabIndexOfType<MyErrorType, ReturnType<typeof getErrorData>>;
```